# Swift dictionary key type

Tags: swift, inheritance, polymorphism, static-methods, swift-dictionary

I have two classes : 
CatHelper and DogHelper, both are inherited from DataHelper and both contain only class functions.

I would like to have a dictionary of type [DataHelper : [String]]

To do that I made DataHelper conform to Hashable + Equatable

But I have difficulties to instantiate such a dictionary. Here is what I've tried so far

```
let apiURLS:[DataHelper : [String]] = [CatHelper : ["abc","def"], DogHelper:["ddd"], DogHelper: ["fff"]]
```

But the compiler says "Cannot convert value of type CatHelper.Type to expected dictionary key of type DataHelper"

Edit :

Then, I would like to iterate through this dictionary to do, in this example

```
CatHelper.feed("abc")
CatHelper.feed("def")
DogHelper.feed("ddd")
DogHelper.feed("fff")
```

In this case, having instance of CatHelper or DogHelper is not useful since I am using only class functions.

Comment: the compiler is correct once again - you try to pass in the actual Class/Type, not an instance of it. That does not work. If you give more context we might be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: I have just edited my question to give more context

Comment: can you elaborate on the "why"? The fact that you want everything to be static is a pain :/

Comment: Well I could change for non static classes but these are Helpers and I thought that Helpers should be static, I don't see a reason for these classes to be static

Answer (score 1):

Since your dictionary is declared this way

```
let apiURLS:[DataHelper : [String]]
```

it means the key must be an instance of type `DataHelper`.

To get an instance of type DataHelper you can write

```
DataHelper()
```

Instances of subclasses of DataHelper are valid as well:

```
CatHelper()
DogHelper()
```

So

```
let apiURLS:[DataHelper:[String]] = [
    CatHelper(): ["abc","def"],
    DogHelper(): ["ddd"],
    DogHelper(): ["fff"]
]
```

### Update

From your comments (and question updated) I see you want the key of the dictionary do be the type of a class, not an instance.

I don't think this is possible because

```
let apiURLS:[DataHelper.Type : [String]] = [
    CatHelper.self: ["abc","def"],
    DogHelper.self: ["ddd"],
    DogHelper.self: ["fff"]
]
error: type 'DataHelper.Type' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
let apiURLS:[DataHelper.Type : [String]] = [
        ^
```

So we cannot use a class type as key of a dictionary.

### Ok let's explore another solution

This Wrapper can contain the type of `DataHelper` or the type of subclass of `DataHelper`.

```
class Wrapper:Hashable, Equatable {
    let value: DataHelper.Type
    init(_ value:DataHelper.Type) {
        self.value = value
    }
    var hashValue: Int { get { return "\(value)".hashValue } }
}

func ==(left:Wrapper, right:Wrapper) -> Bool {
    return left.value == right.value
}
```

Like this

```
Wrapper(CatHelper.self)
```

Since the wrapper is Hashable and Equatable can be used as key in a `Dictionary`.

So now

```
let apiURLS:[Wrapper : [String]] = [
    Wrapper(CatHelper.self): ["abc","def"],
    Wrapper(DogHelper.self): ["ddd"],
    Wrapper(DogHelper.self): ["fff"]
]
```

### Iteration

```
apiURLS
    .map { ($0.0.value, $0.1) }
    .forEach { (classType, strings) -> () in
        classType.feed("Wow")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to have instance of those Helper since I am only using static class functions

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it working after a bit of fiddling around with it:

```
let apiURLS:[(String -> (),[String])] = [(CatHelper.feed, ["abc","def"]), (DogHelper.feed, ["ddd"]), (DogHelper.feed, ["fff"])]

apiURLS.forEach { (f, x) in
    x.forEach {
        f($0)
    }
}
```

The change is basically that you no longer have an dictionary (which would not have worked in the first place due to duplicate keys) but an array. And in the array you have a tuple of the function to call and the inputs.

With the following code as building base line:

```
class DataHelper {
    class func feed(a:String) {
        print("data ate \(a)")
    }
}

class CatHelper : DataHelper {
    override class func feed(a:String) {
        print("cat ate \(a)")
    }
}

class DogHelper : DataHelper {
    override class func feed(a:String) {
        print("dog ate \(a)")
    }
}
```

It outputs

> cat ate abc
>   cat ate def
>   dog ate ddd
>   dog ate fff

Comment: Oh cool, does it sound a bit hacky for you ? Is there a design problem or is it something "normal"

Comment: @Max it still is a *bit* hacky, but since I do not know what exactly the `feed` methods will do and where the actual input will come from I cannot really provide anything else.

Comment: The content of [String] is URLS. I fetch each url (json objects) then for each kind of json, a specific feed method is called. This method feeds an CoreData objet and save it